# Getting document not a function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I am attempting to retrieve the `boolean` child (notificationsOn) of an object stored as a `Firestore` document to see if the rest of a function should be executed.

The overall function works to completion without this portion, but adding the portion from `let threadDoc` to the `if` statement presents a "threadDoc.get is not a function" error. I think my syntax is wrong but I don't know how, as a similar function works in a later part of the function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendDMNotification =functions.firestore.document('/dm_threads/{thread_id}/messages/{message_id}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {


    const newMessage = snapshot.data();

    const senderName = newMessage.authorName;
    const senderID = newMessage.authorUID;
    const messageText = newMessage.message;
    const recipientID = newMessage.recipientUID;
    var notificationsOn = null;

    let deviceTokenQuery = admin.firestore().collection(`/users/${recipientID}/device_tokens/`);

    var idsToBeSorted = [senderID, recipientID];
    idsToBeSorted.sort();
    var threadID = idsToBeSorted[0] + idsToBeSorted[1];


    console.log(recipientID);
    console.log(threadID);


    let threadDoc = admin.firestore().document(`users/${recipientID}/threads/${threadID}/`);

    return threadDoc.get().then(doc => {

        let notificationsOn = doc.data.notificationsOn;
        console.log(notificationsOn);


        if (notificationsOn !== false){


            return deviceTokenQuery.get().then(querySnapshot => {

                let tokenShapshot = querySnapshot.docs;

                const notificationPromises = tokenShapshot.map(doc => {


                    let token_id = doc.data().tokenID;


                    const payload = {

                        data: {

                            title: senderName,
                            body: messageText,
                            senderID: senderID,
                            senderName: senderName

                        }

                    };


                    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {

                        console.log("Notification sent: ", response);
                    })
                        .catch(error => {

                            console.log("Error sending message: ", error);

                        });


                });

                return Promise.all(notificationPromises);

            });


        }

        return;

    });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`admin.firestore().document()` was supposed to be `admin.firestore().collection(...).doc(...)`

This fixed my problem

Comment: This was the answer, and fixed my problem. I edited it to make that clear.

Comment: Hi @aedgar777! Good work finding the solution! Can you [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Planning on it. It's making me wait 8 more hours.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to say `admin.firestore()` instead of `functions.firestore`.

Comment: Not sure if you mean line 6 or line 29, but I get the same error for both if I switch them. functions.firestore on line 6 has been working, this check after the first log statements is what broke everything.

Comment: The `functions` object only helps you build a cloud function.  That's all.  `admin` gives you programmatic access to Firebase products.

Comment: I see. Well I swapped it for admin.firestore().document when initializing threadDoc as written above and I still get the same error in the console. First two log statements print, though.